# CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify PHP Equivalent

Tags: php, cryptojs, encoder

googled looking for an CryptoJS.enc.Hex equivalent function in php. There are many articles on base24 encoding, which were helpful. But base64 encoding is not the same as CryptoJS.enc.Hex encoding.

Basically, the "CryptoJS.enc.Base64" is the same as php base64_encode. Is there a "CryptoJS.enc.Hex" in php, like hex_encode?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: As encryption functions always return bytes I assume you want to convert bytes to hex, did you check https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.bin2hex.php ?

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I had tried hex2bin :-) and did not match, now makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent of `CryptoJS.enx.Hex.stringify` in php is `bin2hex`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php